# React: передать в массив несколько react-компонент

Tags: javascript, массивы, reactjs, классы

Подскажите как правильно реализовать следующую задумку (возможно я микроскопом гвозди забиваю или вообще использую неправильный подход - тогда скорректируйте PLZ)

Итак у меня есть некоторый компонент

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class MyCard extends Component
{
    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                Card #1
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MyCard;
```

И я хочу вывести несколько компонентов из другого компонента:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

import MyCard from './MyCard'

class MyList extends Component
{
    constructor()
    {
        super();

        // задать карточки
        const queryData = [
            <MyCard />
        ];

        // сформировать содержимое
        this.state = {
            m_queryComponents:   queryData.map((params, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <div key = {index}>{params}</div>
                                    );
                                })
        };
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.m_queryComponents}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default MyList;
```

И вроде всё работает корректно, но когда я пытаюсь указать несколько компонент возникает ошибка

```
    // задать карточки
    const queryData = [
        <MyCard />,
        <MyCard />,
        <MyCard />
    ];
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чём ошибка и как исправить.

P.S.

Вообще все это делаю для реализации следующей схемы:

Есть карточки, которые отрисовываются одинаково (отличия только в элементах, которые в них содержатся) и обрабатываются также одинаково.

И есть элементы, которые представляют собой React компоненты, которые уже работают непосредственно с классическими html элементами.

Чтобы не дублировать код обработки хочу сделать универсальный класс, в который передаются элементы и способ работы с ними или наследуется новый класс от универсального (тут не суть, просто универсальный делается "абстрактным")

Поэтому и думал, что можно сделать что-то подобное

```
class My extends Abstract
{
    constructor()
    {
        const data = [
            <ReactElement1 />,
            <ReactElement1 />,
            <ReactElement1 />
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем конкретно ошибка? Перенес ваш код в песочницу. Тут https://codesandbox.io/s/z2qjx711q4 все работает.

Comment: @alum сам не понимаю, проверил свой код - все работает, не знаю, что я делал не так, что у меня выдавались ошибки :( В любом случае спасибо и за песочницу тоже. 

А можно ещё вопросик: - я у компонента могу указывать параметры `<ReactElement1 id = "123" />`. А как добавить параметр не при объявлении, а после (в примере - когда данные из массива в состояние переносятся)? Это ситуация, когда я не знаю при объявлении некоторых параметров, но потом хочу их добавить

Comment: подправил в песочнице https://codesandbox.io/s/z2qjx711q4. Нет смысла компоненты иницилизировать и хранить в state, лучше там хранить описание компонентов и передавать их далее.

Comment: @alum, в приведённом примере вы использовали один компонент MyCard и разные параметры этого компонента, который и передали как массив в состояния. Я же говорил, про то, что в массиве могут сидеть разные компоненты, а ПОЗЖЕ (это важно) я им назначу в зависимости от логики моего приложения какие-то параметры (например, разные ID) и только потом передам в состояния. Вот и думал как это сделать :( Т.е. вся соль, что я сейчас знаю, какие будут компоненты, но только при выполнении узнаю какие у них будут параметры. (хотите могу отдельный пост с вопросом создать для удобства?)

Comment: Обновил в прошлой ссылке. Но с логикой твоего приложения я не согласен. Не стоит делать такой главный компонент который пожирает все то что ему не дали. С оптимизацией будут потом проблемы как по мне.

Comment: @alum, это конечно выход, но вот какой-то внутренней красоты не хватает :(